# How to save wechat qr code for print purpose?

Tags: wechat

I am registered my wechat account through phone number. I have the qr code and I tried to share it to facebook, then download it to my pc, but the image is small, not suitable for print purpose.

Anyone has any idea how can I generate a big QR code for print purpose?

Answer (score 0):

- Log in https://mp.weixin.qq.com/
- click on 公众号设置 on the side menu
- click on the QR code in the 二维码 section

The downloading should proceed.

Edit: this is in case you have a wechat official account.
If it is a personal account :

- click "me" on the app menu
- click on your profile picture on the top
- click on "My QR Code"
- there is an option button on the top bar of the app. Click it and click on "save to phone"

The quality should be good enough